# I want to connect a Spring Boot application to MSSQL where username having dot (.) operator

Tags: java

Below is my application properties file image

When I am running application its giving me an error as 'login failed for user umang.jaiswal'

Comment: Link for application properties file https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfDgh.png

Comment: Blank password?

Comment: yes I am connecting for Windows Authentication in MSSQL server management studio so there is no password

Comment: Windows authentication doesn’t work from Java.

Comment: okay, I will try and check by using SQL server Authentication

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

try as [umang.jaiswal] with square brackets

Comment: [umang.jaiswal] with square brackets is also not working